# Preventing from entering unwanted value with in stream

Tags: c++, string, cin

it's my second post here.

I want to ask about concept of std::cin, I want to make a program that saves personal info and shows it in the stream, but I need to make sure that user can't enter value type different than string and int in "name, surname, age" variables.
Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void getInformation(std::string & name, std::string & surname, int & age) {
    std::cout << "Enter name: ";
    std::cin >> name;

    std::cout << "Enter surname: ";
    std::cin >> surname;

    std::cout << "Enter age: ";
    std::cin >> age;
}

void showInformation(std::string name, std::string surname, int age) {
    std::cout << "Name: " << name << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Surname: " << surname << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Age: " << age << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    std::string name[ 2 ];
    std::string surname[ 2 ];
    int age[ 2 ];

    for( int i = 0; i < 2; i++ )
        getInformation( name[ i ], surname[ i ], age[ i ] );

    for( int i = 0; i < 2; i++ )
        showInformation( name[ i ], surname[ i ], age[ i ] );
    return 0;
}
```

I know it's quite basic question, but I find it really hard to deal with cin.good, cin.sync. I would be grateful if somebody could explain the basic concept of dealing with those problems.

Comment: The most common way is, to record everything that is entered in a string or a variable type that can contain everything and than validate the input by checking, if it is a number or whatever criteria one has to apply to the input. After that the input can be casted to an appropriate format like int depending on the information you want to store.

Comment: Please clarify the question. Suppose the age is being entered. Which behavior do you want to achieve: (1) if user enters a string with non-digit characters, the age is queried again or (2) if user hits a non-digit key on a keyboard, nothing happens (this character is not even shown on the console screen)?

Comment: The (1)st one is my exact intention.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on Aeonos comment,  I would suggest to first record all inputs into a *std::string*, and then convert the values by using some conversion library, e.g. [boost::lexical_cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html).

Answer (score 0):

There is no way in standard C++ to prevent a user from providing input in a form different that the program expects.

The most that is possible is reading all input in some form, analysing the input, discarding the parts that are not wanted, and interpreting the rest as needed.

One example, as mentioned by Aeonos in comments, would be to read all data to a `std::string` (e.g. using `std::getline(std::cin, some_std_string)`).   Once the string is read, it can be checked to see if it contains a name (however you specify that) or an integer (presumably it only contains digits, if you expect a positive integer to be input).   If the string doesn't contain the required form of input, discard the input, and repeat the process (e.g. in a loop).   If it does contain input in the required form, extract the required values.

Generally you will not use the input streaming operator (`cin >> whatever`) to do this - the options for error checking are too limited.